# \noindent creates extra space when inside custom environment

Tags: spacing, environments, line-spacing, white-space

I wanted to create a `newenvironment` which included a `minipage`. However, I discovered that when inserting the `\noindent` command inside this `minipage` it creates extra space in the beginning of the line. Additionally, this spaces seems to be different when the text is long!

Also, the vertical spacing seems to behave differently within and outside a minipage.

[image]

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Here is the code that created this picture:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

\newenvironment{sample_text_with_noindentation}{\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}\noindent}{\end{minipage}}
\newenvironment{sample_text_without_noindentation}{\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}}{\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\hrulefill
\begin{center}minipage in document\end{center}
\hrulefill

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \noindent random short text............
\end{minipage}
Horizontal spacing looks fine here,

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    random short text............
\end{minipage}
but the first row seems further apart

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \noindent random text which very long long long very long very long and it goes beyond the margins so it reaches the other line............
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    random text which very long long long very long very long and it goes beyond the margins so it reaches the other line............
\end{minipage}

\hrulefill
\begin{center}minipage with {$\backslash$}noindent in {$\backslash$}newenvironment in preamble\end{center}
\hrulefill

\begin{sample_text_with_noindentation}
    \noindent random short text............
\end{sample_text_with_noindentation}
Seems there is an extra space

\begin{sample_text_with_noindentation}
    random short text............
\end{sample_text_with_noindentation}
even with {$\backslash$}noindent

\begin{sample_text_with_noindentation}
    \noindent random text which very long long long very long very long and it goes beyond the margins so it reaches the other line............
\end{sample_text_with_noindentation}
which is bigger for long text

\begin{sample_text_with_noindentation}
    random text which very long long long very long very long and it goes beyond the margins so it reaches the other line............
\end{sample_text_with_noindentation}
again even with {$\backslash$}noindent

\hrulefill
\begin{center}minipage without {$\backslash$}noindent in {$\backslash$}newenvironment in preamble\end{center}
\hrulefill

\begin{sample_text_without_noindentation}
    \noindent random short text............
\end{sample_text_without_noindentation}
However, if you remove {$\backslash$}noindent

\begin{sample_text_without_noindentation}
    random short text............
\end{sample_text_without_noindentation}
from the custom environment,

\begin{sample_text_without_noindentation}
    \noindent random text which very long long long very long very long and it goes beyond the margins so it reaches the other line............
\end{sample_text_without_noindentation}
everything looks fine

\begin{sample_text_without_noindentation}
    random text which very long long long very long very long and it goes beyond the margins so it reaches the other line............
\end{sample_text_without_noindentation}
(except the vertical spacing)

\hrulefill

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that the `\noindent` puts you into horizontal mode at the end of the `\begin{sample_text_with_noindentation}` so as a consequence the new line after `\begin{sample_text_with_noindentation}` is interpreted as a space. The simple solution is to add `\ignorespaces` after `\noindent`.

Comment: So, why is there a space of different length when the text is long? And why is the vertical spacing like this?

Comment: The space is an ordinary inter-word space. In your third case, the space is larger because it stretches to justfiy the line. The vertical spacing is because the minipage does not have any depth on the last line. You could add `\strut` before `\end{minipage}` and that would work, although you need to take care that the `\strut` doesn't go to a new line. Something like `\ifhmode\unskip\strut\fi` should do the trick.

Comment: I see. This makes sense now, thank you very much!